# How can I send keys to a hidden password box

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to login to a site `www.bet365.com`

I am able to send the login information for the username, however the password box is split into both a visible and hidden element for security.

How am I able to send the password to the box in order to automate login?

I have tried accessing the visible element however when passed not all characters of the password are received.

When attempting to pass to the hidden element no password is visibly sent.

I have also tried clicking the visible element before sending but this also did not work.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,3)
userele=wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.hm-Login_UserNameWrapper input.hm-Login_InputField[type="text"]')))
userele.send_keys('xyz@gmail.com')

passwdele=wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper input.hm-Login_InputField.Hidden[type="password"]')))
passwdele.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxxx')

btnelement=wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper button.hm-Login_LoginBtn')))

btnelement.click()
```

Here is the main code for the elements on the bet365 page

```
<div class="hm-HeaderModule_UserAdmin ">
<div class="hm-Login ">

<div class="hm-Login_UserNameWrapper ">
<input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
<div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Join Now</div></div>

<div class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ">
<input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
<input type="password" class="hm-Login_InputField Hidden ">
<button tabindex="0" class="hm-Login_LoginBtn ">GO</button>
<div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Lost Login?</div></div></div></div>
```

Only the username passing currently works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can send the password in visible input like this :

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'chromedriverPath')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@title='New Customer Bonus']"))).click()

userele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.hm-Login_UserNameWrapper input.hm-Login_InputField[type='text']")))
userele.send_keys('xyz@gmail.com')

passwdele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper input.hm-Login_InputField[type='text']")))
passwdele.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxxx')

btnelement = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper button.hm-Login_LoginBtn')))

btnelement.click()
```

**imports would be :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Let me know, if you are facing any problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, however this is still cropping up the same issue of only 4 of the password keys being sent, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid invoking `send_keys()` to a hidden password box in all possible ways. However inducing *WebDriverWait* for the first element on the page you want to interact would be enough and you don't need to invoke *WebDriverWait* multiple times when interacting with `<input>` elements. You can try either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hm-Login_UserNameWrapper>input.hm-Login_InputField[type='text']"))).send_keys('xyz@gmail.com')
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper>input.hm-Login_InputField:not(.Hidden)").send_keys("hello")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hm-Login_UserNameWrapper ']/input[@class='hm-Login_InputField ' and @type='text']"))).send_keys('xyz@gmail.com')
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']/input[contains(@class, 'hm-Login_InputField') and not(@class='Hidden')]").send_keys("Jp1875")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your help! still having a couple issues with it but will have a play around under your advice

Comment: @Jp1875 Exactly what **issue** are you facing now?

Comment: It still seems to be trimming the password keys sent so not all end up in the password box